# How to change documentroot of subdomain with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to change the documentroot  of my subdomain in directadmin but I couldn't find anything . Now I want to do it with .htaccess .

mysubdomain.test.com

should open follow address

test.com/folder1/folder2

I did this but It didn't work .

```
#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysubdomain.test.com
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder1/folder2/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

and I got this error .

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was 
unable to complete your request.
```

Comment: Can you please share what you tried so far?

Comment: sure . I added it .

Comment: What folder is your subdomain currently pointing to?

Comment: I got server error

Answer (score 2):

In your attempt you created an endless rewriting loop. Your http server's error log file would say so. Always keep in mind to monitor that log file!

You either need to add a condition to break the loop:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysubdomain\.test\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder1/folder2
RewriteRule ^ /folder1/folder2%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Or you use the `END` flag instead of the `L` flag which terminates the rewriting process immediately instead of triggering another run, the loop:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysubdomain\.test\.com$
RewriteRule ^ /folder1/folder2%{REQUEST_URI} [END]
```

Comment: Thanks, I used it but I got file not found error now .

Comment: So what URL did you request and where would the corresponding file be in the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` ?